# Request.getParameterMap values not castable to string

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

i am trying to get the complete parameter map from the request object and iterate over it.

here is the sample code

```
  Map map = request.getParameterMap();
for(Object key : map.keySet()){
    String keyStr = (String)key;
    Object value = map.get(keyStr);     
    System.out.println("Key " + (String)key + "     :    " + value);
}
```

output

```
  Key businessunit     :    [Ljava.lang.String;@388f8321
   Key site     :    [Ljava.lang.String;@55ea0889
  Key startDate     :    [Ljava.lang.String;@77d6866f
  Key submit     :    [Ljava.lang.String;@25141ee0
  Key traffictype     :    [Ljava.lang.String;@4bf71724
```

its evident from the output that the value object is an instance of String

```
now when i change my code to something like this

  Map map = request.getParameterMap();
  for(Object key : map.keySet()){
    String keyStr = (String)key;
    Object value = map.get(keyStr);
    if(value instanceof String)
    System.out.println("Key " + (String)key + "     :    " + (String)value);
}
```

it prints nothing  but as per the previous output it should have printed the values and if i remove instanceOf check it gives ClassCastException. is this the expected behavior or i am doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Three possibilities: 1. Did you redeclare class `String` somewhere (try using `java.lang.String` instead of `String` to find out)? 2. Are you using the exact same values when running the two pieces of code? 3. Try using `String.valueOf(value)` or `value.toString()` and see what happens. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah forget the above, it's an array. Fooled me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[Ljava.lang.String;@XXXXXXX` means it is array of `String` not a single `String`. So your condition fails and it does not print anything.

Answer (score 7):

As the object which is returned is an array of strings as Harry Joy pointed out, you will have to use the `Arrays.toString()` method in order to convert that array to a printable string:

```
    Map map = request.getParameterMap();
    for (Object key: map.keySet())
    {
            String keyStr = (String)key;
            String[] value = (String[])map.get(keyStr);
            System.out.println("Key" + (String)key + "   :   " + Arrays.toString(value));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The value is an array. If you're sure that the array is not empty, you should get the string value like this:

```
String value = (String) map.get(keyStr)[0];
```